# Is Poe's X-Wing modified?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

As the best starfighter pilot in the galaxy, does Poe enjoy the privilege of a technically more advanced X-Wing model or at least the freedom to modify it? Is it technically different from stock X-Wings of the period?

Comment: @DVK Yeap, but I asked for technical differences "under the skin"

Comment: We are talking J.J. Abrams here, still? If so, under the skin is far less important than paint job :) Look at the hash he made out of Starkiller engineering

Comment: In-universe. I was wondering if novelisations mentioned anything. After all, the Millennium Falcon was mentioned to be a modified Corellian freighter.

Comment: Does the fact that Poe's X-Wing actually gets destroyed on Jakku in the film start and he flies another one suffice to indicate it isn't modified?

Comment: @DVK I didn't catch the colour - was the one at the start black? Poe is known to fly a uniquely black X-Wing, and Kylo Ren did not initially realize his true identity. He could have flown a regular X-Wing to travel incognito.

Comment: It looked kinda blue to me but not sure

Comment: well modified in case of Poes x-wing just means different colour ( black ) and beeing able to do what no other aircraft can do or is designed to. That shot of Poe flying above the planet while the stormtroppers are assauting the outpost is soooo far beyond ridiculous that is laughable. No pilot or craft can perform moves like that, no human can withstand G forces like that, no craft can turn on a dime like that. specially an X wing.

Comment: @Cherubel It's not Earth, so nothing is impossible.

Comment: ok then lets agree to answwr all the answers about TFA with "magic". As Poes X wing even with beeing "special" isnt supposed to be doing things his fighter did. so the custom part of his ship is magic.

Comment: @Cherubel I'm speaking on the basis that their technology allows them to do things not possible within the bounds of the current beliefs of Earth-based physics, such as faster-than-light and dark matter harnessing. On those grounds, we cannot say what is impossible on Earth is similarly so there. They may have technology or materials that make these possible. Differing planetary conditions also changes circumstances. We simply can't assume their entire galaxy is like Earth.

Comment: @DVK The X-Wing destroyed on Jakku is a blue and white one, similar to the ones used by several other pilots in the film. It's not until Poe returns to the Resistance base that his black and orange X-Wing is seen.

Comment: @Cherubel - G-forces only matter if you can't control gravity. In Star Wars they can control gravity.

Answer (score 5):

Unknown.

TFA Incredible Cross-Sections page 12 says:

> "The T-70 X-wing is a favourite craft of Resistance pilots, including Poe Dameron, who flies a customised example codenamed Black One."

However, what constitutes "customized" is not clear - it could refer to its custom black color; or to special configuration of modular bays (which ALL T-70s have according to the book), OR real customization not available to other X-Wings.

Neither novelization nor film script mention specific details.

Comment: *"Set X-Foils to 'sell toys' mode"*

Comment: @DVK I would venture a guess that, by convention, that meant technical customization. If it's just a paint job, the word customised isn't usually used. There's no strict enforcement, ofc, but typically "customised" indicates modifications of a technical nature has necessarily been made to be called that. "Variant" is more conveniently used for both include-technical and aesthetic only differences

Comment: Worth remembering that Poe has two. The one that blows up on Jakku and the one flying at the end of the film. Would they both be custom versions?

Comment: @JeremyFrench - I seriously doubt that he would consider a BLUE X-Wing "his". Probably a temporary loaner or something. He doesn't seem like the type to fly normal colored craft from Visual Dictionary descriptions of him

Comment: @DVK if his mission at the start of the movie is undercover or behind enemy lines, he would certainly not fly his signature fighter to avoid enemy identification of such a HVT

Answer (score 5):

As the Rebel force's acknowledged "top pilot" Poe appears to have had some latitude to customise the ships at his disposal.

As well as explicitly confirming that Poe's "Black One" X-wing is a customised ship, the film's '[Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections)' book states that the black paint is more than just an affectation, it's actually a

> "Sensor-scattering ferrospehere paint"

The film's "[Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)" backs this up, stating that that the paint-job makes his X-wing especially hard to track and easily

> overlooked by sensors.

Presumably this aids his dogfighting (the ship is hard to see on sensors and visually) as well as making it useful for the sort of *infiltration* mission he's on at the start of the film.

Comment: so the paint does serve a purpose! Such a thing exists in real life too. Although the mission at the start didn't feature that particular fighter it seems. I assume there's no mention of any other modifications?

Comment: @thegreatjedi - It's unclear what features are non-standard, other than the paint which doesn't appear on the other x-wings

Comment: [Yet another confirmation of the special paint.](https://twitter.com/starwars/status/821409255597211648)

Comment: My question would be, if this paint gives you an advantage then why aren't all fighters painted with it?: Only one can in the universe?

Comment: @Mwarren - Why aren't all fighter jets painted black and covered in radar-reflecting paint like the Stealth?

Comment: @Valorum I understand what you are getting at, but if it just paint then why is there apparently only one fighter painted that way that we know of?

Comment: @mwarren - Most x-wings are intended for fighting other (also visible) ships. Poe's is intended for him to sneak around in, hence the sneaky paintjob.

Comment: @Valorum Fair enough, I know comments are not for extended chat, I just thought that if it was only a paint job then it would be advantageous for all x-wings to have it. Shutting up now.

Comment: @mwarren - I was just going to suggest that you should ask it as a separate question...

Comment: I've asked the question, it might need tidying up as I am very near going to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

According to *The Last Jedi: Incredible Cross-Sections*:

> Poe Dameron's customized T-70, *Black One*, returned from Starkiller Base with a bad case of carbon-scoring and dangerously frayed fire-control linkages. (p. 16)

Since Poe returns from Starkiller Base during *The Force Awakens*, we can infer that it was already customized during that film.

Furthermore, its rear thruster seen in *The Last Jedi* was a visible customization:

> To give himself an edge in combat, Poe ordered that an experimental thrust accelerator pod be added to *Black One*'s propulsion system. (ibid)