# Has Poe Dameron's X-Wing been majorly upgraded between The Force Awakens and The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In the trailer for The Last Jedi released on October 9, 2017, we see what seems to be a new upgrade on a Resistance X-Wing - a large, central thruster of some sort, mounted right behind the hyperdrive.

[image]
[image]

As the thruster fires, it seems like the X-Wing matches Poe's from the previous movie. At least, it seems dark in color, with orange markings.

[image]

The scene then cuts to a close-up of Poe's eyes as he flies, further implying that this is his X-Wing. However, I don't recall seeing a thruster on his X-Wing in this position in The Force Awakens - or, for that matter, on any X-Wing variant in the past.

This may not be answerable yet - and there evidently [wasn't a lot of information about it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113876/is-poes-x-wing-modified) last time around. But has this been covered in any other supplementary materials? For instance, did his X-Wing get a tune-up post-Force Awakens in any of the comic books or novels?

Or do we need to wait for the new Incredible Cross-Sections book? :)

Comment: Seems like a Future Works thing.

Comment: Are you saying Poe Dameron boosted first?

Comment: It's an XX wing now

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### This is unique for Poe

In [a preview](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/last-jedi-exclusive-poe-dameron-improved-x-wing-revealed/) for their October issue, *Empire Magazine* revealed some comments from director Rian Johnson that confirm this:

> The X-Wing (an Incom-FreiTek T-70, to be precise) has, according to Rian Johnson, been specially modified by Resistance engineers, with a temporary accelerator pod affixed to the aft section. According to *The Last Jedi* director, the pod, when primed, increases Dameron's speed, allowing him to outrun First Order cannon emplacements. It’s just a temporary boost and will burn out quickly but it’s enough to get beyond the barrage of turbo laser fire from First Order Star Destroyers such as the one depicted in the image.

### It isn't completely new, but does appear to be an upgrade

*The Force Awakens Incredible Cross-Sections* shows that Poe's fighter already had some special engine, called a "turbo impeller", which appears substantially similar to what's seen in the trailer:

[image]

However, it seems as though Poe's gotten an upgrade since then; several sources suggest this:

- [Bandai](http://bandai-hobby.net/item/2114/)'s licensed model kit<sup>1</sup> (translated from the Japanese by recognizer, courtesy of Google translate):

  > The Boosted Accelerator Pod is a feature of the Last Jedi version of Poe's X-Wing
- [Revell](https://www.revell.de/en/products/star-wars/star-wars-episode-viii/id/06763.html)'s licensed model kit<sup>1</sup>:

  > Poe's boosted X-wing fighter from the new film Star Wars: The Last Jedi.
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > To give ace pilot Poe Dameron an edge in combat, Resistance engineers have fitted a boosted accelerator pod onto the tail of his T-70 X-wing.
- An inset in *Empire Magazine*'s October issue:

  [image]

  > **Bottom right:** Poe's X-Wing, outfitted with a new booster to outmanoeuvre First Order guns

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to recognizer for hunting these links down

Comment: Ah, nice catch with that interview quote! I just found a tidbit while looking for other info on this, which I'm gonna add into your answer.

Comment: @recognizer Intriguing finds; I'd like to include the relevant information from each link, for archiving purposes, but I can't read your first one. Can you translate the essential information and add it in? I can get the second one myself

Comment: You gotta update the in-universe models so you can move that merch!

Comment: @JasonBaker Oh, weird! In my web browser, the Bandai site auto-translates itself once the page fully loads. The translation's not very good, but between it and Google Translate, it merely says that the "Boosted Accelerator Pod" is "a feature of the Last Jedi version of Poe's X-Wing" and that it's reproduced in detail.

Comment: @recognizer Cheers; my browser auto-translates too, but I saw "The engine part "Boosted · Accelerator · Pod" which is the feature of the "Star Wars / last Jedi" version of the pa wing machine is amazing as well as the Ace pilot of resistance" and decided not to trust that translation

Comment: @JasonBaker No, it's not my browser. On my end the site asynchronously refreshes with translated text without any user action. As I didn't tell it to translate the page, and in any case I'm using Chrome and it doesn't match the Google Translate results, the English text (whatever its provenance) is definitely being supplied by Bandai's site.